# Visual studio 2010 is not executing code after including gmock.LIB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, googletest, googlemock

Earlier I was using `gtest` for my project. For the time being I am using `gmock` and when I have provided the path for `gmock.lib`, `gmock_mock.lib` and `..\..\include` too. Then the control is not at all going into the `code`.

Suppose previously it was like e.g.

```
main()
{
printf("Hello world"); //Kept the breakpoint here, control comes here
}
```

Now after adding `.lib` and `include` paths it is not at all executing just strats debug and ends without going anywhere...

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Google test lets you write unit tests using the `TEST` macro. It is not intended for use with normal programs that already have a `main()`. If you want to use google test you should create another project.